# HuggingFace Trainer do predictions

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, fine-tuning

I've been fine-tuning a Model from HuggingFace via the `Trainer`-Class.
I went through the Training Process via `trainer.train()` and also tested it with `trainer.evaluate()`.

My question is how I can run the Model on specific data.
In case of a classification text I'm looking for sth like this:

```
trainer.predict('This text is about football')
output = 'Sports'
```

Do I need to save the Model first or is there a command I can use directly? What's the most simple way on running the fine-tuned Model?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/text-classification/run_xnli.py#L415

It shows you the way to train, evaluate, and predict with the class transformers.Trainer

Comment: Thank you a lot! Is there also a way to predict a single datarow (with only Features/no Label) instead of a whole dataset?

Comment: @Infomagier If you relay on the transformers.Trainer class, you can make a dataset with only one sample (maybe with a fake label). Another way to accomplish you goal is to implement the training and evaluating procedure for your self. Check https://huggingface.co/course/chapter3/4?fw=pt for example.